# Rotating squares animation

Tags: graphics, geometry, animation, generative-art

[image]
Reference link: https://www.geogebra.org/m/RHYH3UQ8 , https://www.geogebra.org/m/xkzsqcyx , https://www.netpad.net.cn/svg.html#posts/55789

I want to generate an rotating squares animation like this, my code only workd for 3×3 squares, how can I expand to more squares ( (2n-1) × (2n-1) )?

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};

Manipulate[Graphics[{
   EdgeForm[Gray], LightRed,
   RotationTransform[θ + Pi/2, #]@pts & /@ pts // Polygon,

   LightGreen, Polygon[pts],
   TranslationTransform[RotationTransform[θ + Pi/2, #2]@# - #]@pts & @@@
     Partition[pts, 2, 1, 1] // Polygon
   }, PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-2, 3}}], {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Build a chessboard without rotating:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray],
  Table[{If[Mod[i+j, 2]==0,LightRed,LightGreen],Rectangle[{i,j}]},{i,5},{j,5}]} ]
```

or

```
ArrayPlot[Mod[Array[Plus,{5,5}],2],ColorRules->{0->LightRed,1->LightGreen},Mesh->All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I made a similar animation once with plusses:

[image]

I changed the shape of the plus to a square. Here is the code:

```
\[CurlyPhi] = Tan[1/3.];
Clear[DrawPlus, MakeScene]
DrawPlus[p : {x_, y_}, \[Theta]_] := Module[{line},
  (*line=Polygon[{{1,1},{3,1},{3,-1},{1,-1},{1,-3},{-1,-3},{-1,-1},{-3,-\
1},{-3,1},{-1,1},{-1,3},{1,3},{1,1}}];*)
  line = Polygon[{{3, 1}, {1, -3}, {-3, -1}, {-1, 3}}];

  line = GeometricTransformation[line, RotationMatrix[\[Theta]]];
  GeometricTransformation[line, TranslationTransform[p]]
  ]
MakeScene[\[Alpha]_] := Module[{p, q, \[Theta] = \[Pi] \[Alpha], gr},
  p = {1., -3.} + 
    Sqrt[10] {Cos[\[Theta] - \[CurlyPhi]], -Sin[\[Theta] - \
\[CurlyPhi]]};
  q = {3., 1.} + 
    Sqrt[10] {Sin[\[Theta] - \[CurlyPhi]], 
      Cos[\[Theta] - \[CurlyPhi]]};
  gr = Flatten[
    Table[DrawPlus[i p + j q, If[EvenQ[i + j], 0, -\[Theta]]], {i, -3,
       3}, {j, -3, 3}], 1];
  (*gr=GeometricTransformation[gr,RotationMatrix[\[Theta]/2]];*)

  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]], RGBColor[0, 0.5, 1], 
    gr}, PlotRange -> (16 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}), ImageSize -> 300]
  ]
Manipulate[MakeScene[\[Beta]], {\[Beta], 0, 1}]
```

resulting in:
[image]

I think you can figure out alternate coloring and rotating the entire scene. To change the extent of the squares change the bounds of the **Table** function.

Probably it can be simplified because I had another geometry. But you can study the mechanism and either adopt mine or adjust your own.

Comment: An explanation would be nice, especially how you found the expressions for `q` and `p`.

Comment: p and q can be found by some geometry, nothing special actually. They are the center-to-center 'unit vectors' of the squares in both directions.

Answer (score 13):

This almost, but not quite, matches the requested figure.

```
square = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
n = 5;
redlattice = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {y, -n + 1, n}, {x, -n + 1, n}], 1];
greenlattice = Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {y, -n + 1, n - 1}, {x, -n + 1, n - 1}], 1];

Manipulate[
 redsquares = RotationTransform[θ + π/2, #]@square & /@ redlattice;
 temp = RotationTransform[θ + π/2, #]@square & /@ greenlattice;
 greensquares = TranslationTransform[#[[1]] - square[[1]]]@square & /@ temp;
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
   LightRed, Polygon@redsquares,
   LightGreen, Polygon[square], Polygon@greensquares
   }, PlotRange -> {{-2 n - 1, 2 n + 2}, {-2 n - 1, 2 n + 2}}], {θ, 0, π}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Extending @ MelaGo answer...in spirit of OP...but needs improvement:

```
square = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};
f[j_, k_] := Table[{u, k}, {u, -j, j}];
top[n_] := Join @@ (f @@@ Table[{n - j, j}, {j, 0, n}]);
bot[n_] := Join @@ (f @@@ Table[{n - j, -j}, {j, 1, n}]);
full[n_] := Join[top[n], bot[n]];

funr[p_] := RegionCentroid[Polygon[RotationTransform[Pi/2, p]@square]]
fung[p_] := 
 RegionCentroid[
  Polygon[TranslationTransform[(RotationTransform[Pi/2, p]@
        square)[[1]]]@square]]
lattr[n_] := Select[full[n], funr[#][[1]] != -n - 1/2 &]
lattg[n_] := Select[full[n], fung[#][[1]] != n + 1/2 &]
vis[a_, n_] := Module[{red = lattr[n], green = lattg[n], rs, tmp, gs},
  rs = RotationTransform[a + \[Pi]/2, #]@square & /@ red;
  tmp = RotationTransform[a + \[Pi]/2, #]@square & /@ green;
  gs = TranslationTransform[#[[1]]]@square & /@ tmp;
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], LightRed, Polygon@rs, LightGreen, 
    Polygon@gs}, PlotRange -> {{-2 n, 2 n}, {-2 n, 2 n}}]]
Manipulate[vis[a, n], {a, 0, \[Pi]}, {n, Range[2, 7]}]
```

[image]

Some exported gifs:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I modified the SHuisman's code a bit. It turned out to be almost a complete match with the required animation.

```
\[CurlyPhi] = Tan[1/3.];
Clear[DrawPlus, MakeScene]
DrawPlus[p : {x_, y_}, \[Theta]_] := 
 Module[{line}, line = Polygon[{{3, 1}, {1, -3}, {-3, -1}, {-1, 3}}];
  line = GeometricTransformation[line, RotationMatrix[\[Theta]]];
  GeometricTransformation[line, TranslationTransform[p]]]
MakeScene[\[Alpha]_] := 
 Module[{p, q, \[Theta] = \[Pi] \[Alpha], gr}, 
  p = {1., -3.} + 
    Sqrt[10] {Cos[\[Theta] - \[CurlyPhi]], -Sin[\[Theta] - \
\[CurlyPhi]]};
  q = {3., 1.} + 
    Sqrt[10] {Sin[\[Theta] - \[CurlyPhi]], 
      Cos[\[Theta] - \[CurlyPhi]]};
  gr = Flatten[
    Table[{If[OddQ[i + j], LightRed, LightGreen], 
      DrawPlus[i p + j q, If[EvenQ[i + j], 0, -\[Theta]]]}, {i, -3, 
      3}, {j, -3, 3}], 1];
  Graphics[{{EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue, Opacity[.5]]], 
     Rotate[gr, Pi/7]}, {Red, PointSize[.01], 
     Point[{{0, 0}, {2, 2}}]}}, PlotRange -> (30 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}), 
   ImageSize -> 500]]
lst = Table[MakeScene[\[Beta]], {\[Beta], 0, 1, .02}];
ListAnimate[lst]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Answer (score 9):

[image]

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}};

ClearAll[p, nextpt, redsquares, greensquares]

nextpt = AssociationThread[pts, RotateRight[pts]];

p[m_] := Tuples[{SparseArray[DiamondMatrix[m - 1]]["NonzeroPositions"] - m, pts}]

redsquares[t_, m_] := Rotate[Rectangle[], t + Pi/2, #] & /@ DeleteDuplicates[Total /@ p[m]]

greensquares[t_, m_] := Translate[Rectangle[], 
  DeleteDuplicates[RotationTransform[t + Pi/2, nextpt[#2] + #]@#2 - #2 & @@@ p[m]]]
```

Show one or more groups of rotating rectangles:

```
n = 10;
Manipulate[Row[Table[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
  LightRed, redsquares[θ, m], LightGreen, Rectangle[], greensquares[θ, m]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2 m, 2 m + 1}, {-2 m, 2 m + 1}}, 
    ImageSize -> 200 m/2], {m, Sort @ ml}], Spacer[5]], 
 {{ml, {1}}, Range[n], TogglerBar}, {θ, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

The animation above produced using

```
ml = {1, 2, 4}; 
frames = Table[Row[Table[Graphics[{EdgeForm[Gray], 
    LightRed, redsquares[θ, m], LightGreen, Rectangle[], greensquares[θ, m]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2 m, 2 m + 1}, {-2 m, 2 m + 1}}, ImageSize -> 200 m/2], 
 {m, ml}], Spacer[5]], {θ, 0, Pi, Pi/64}];

Export["rotatingrectangles.gif", frames]
```

Comment: I really like your answer.

Comment: Thank you @ubpdqn.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by SHuisman, using complex number

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Table[With[{k = Mod[i + j, 2]}, {EdgeForm[Gray], RGBColor[k, 1 - k, 0, .2],
      Polygon@ReIm[(1 + I) (E^(I θ) + I) (i + I j) +  E^(I k θ) {-1-I, I-1, 1+I, 1-I}]}],
    {i, -n, n}, {j, -n, n}]
   }, PlotRange -> 4 n + 2
  ], {{n, 3}, 1, 9, 1}, {θ, 0., Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great simple and efficient code!