# Shortest way to make a checkerboard pattern

Tags: plotting, graphics, style

I'm looking for the shortest (in terms of characters) code snippet to make an n-square checkerboard.  Here's my first try (comes in at 72 characters):

```
Graphics@{PatternFilling["Checkerboard", ImageScaled[1/10]], 
  Rectangle[]}
```

[image]

And my second try, which is a bit shorter (42 characters):

```
Image @ Table[.5 + (-1)^(i + j)/2, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: ```Graphics@{"Checkerboard"~PatternFilling~ImageScaled[1/10],Rectangle[]}``` would shave off 1 character…

Comment: 52 characters: `Graphics@{PatternFilling@"Checkerboard",Rectangle[]}`

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/206302/7339 and https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71093/90804

Comment: Mathematica ought to help us find the shortest code to do the job! After all, computer systems are supposed to do work for us, not the other way around.

Answer (score 10):

28 characters:

```
Image@Array[(-1)^+## &, {8, 8}]
```

[image]

12 key strokes:

```
=chess board
```

[image]

Comment: Wow and i thought @boomboom answer is unshortable :-) Cool stuff.

Comment: You should post this as an answer to the [code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/71093), it beats [Martin Ender's 34-byte answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71100). If the Wolfram Alpha version is acceptable, it beats [the current shortest answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71156).

Comment: `Image[(-1)^ToeplitzMatrix@8]`

Answer (score 9):

Try `Image[Array[Mod[#+#2,2]&,{8,8}]]`

Comment: You can use `@` rather than `[...]` to save 1 character

Comment: .`Image@Array[Mod[+##,2]&,{8,8}]` saves two characters.